# What is the difference in RISCV between JAL and JALR?

Tags: assembly

I'm kinda confused on what the difference is between the two instructions and would love a comparison of the two!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JAL** saves the next address (program counter +4) to the destination register, adds the immediate value encoded in the instruction to the **program counter**, and jumps to that address.

**JALR** saves the next address (program counter +4) to the destination register, adds the immediate value encoded in the instruction to the **source register**, and jumps to that (*even*) address.

In other words, while **JAL** jumps to an address relative to the current instruction, **JALR** jumps to an even address relative to one stored in a register.

The detailed parts from the technical documentation are these:

> Unconditional Jumps
> The jump and link (JAL) instruction uses the J-type format, where the J-immediate encodes a
> signed offset in multiples of 2 bytes. The offset is sign-extended and added to the pc to form the
> jump target address. Jumps can therefore target a ±1 MiB range. JAL stores the address of the
> instruction following the jump (pc+4) into register rd. The standard software calling convention
> uses x1 as the return address register and x5 as an alternate link register. Plain unconditional jumps (assembler pseudo-op J) are encoded as a JAL with rd=x0.

> The indirect jump instruction JALR (jump and link register) uses the I-type encoding. The target
> address is obtained by adding the 12-bit signed I-immediate to the register rs1, then setting the
> least-significant bit of the result to zero. The address of the instruction following the jump (pc+4)
> is written to register rd. Register x0 can be used as the destination if the result is not required.